# Only charge Stripe subscription in certain months of the year

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am looking to create a Stripe subscription in line with UK school term times. This means I do not want to charge the user in certain months, such as April or December, but I do want to charge them for the rest of the year.

For example:

```
September - charge £10
October - charge £10
November - charge £10
December - charge nothing
January - charge £10
```

etc etc

What would be the best way to implement this?

I have read about subscription phases, and also usage based pricing. Im not sure which one would work best in this scenario.

Comment: This is not really possible directly with Stripe without some custom logic. You'd need to build something that listens for the subscription/invoice events and then switches the subscription on or off based on whether this months is expected to have an invoice or not. I'd recommend talking to Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: @koopajah Would it not be possible to define certain phases when I construct the subscription?

Comment: Not long term. You could define the phases but at the end of the schedule you'd go back to a normal Subscription. You'd need to repeat the phases over and over otherwise.

Comment: @koopajah The subscriptions should only be valid for a year anyway as it is designed to last one school year

Comment: Ah then yes that would work totally fine by defining the right phases to decide when to charge and when to move them to quantity 0

Answer (score 1):

If your Subscription doesn't need to renew after the first year, the best option is to use [Subscription Schedules](https://.stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules). The idea here is to create a Subscription Schedule and define its phases so that in some cases you charge for the Subscription and in others you don't. When you charge, you define a phase with a Price for the monthly fee. When you don't, you can either change the `quantity` to 0 or move them to a Price with a £0 amount instead to reflect this.